# Prohibit parameter combinations

Tags: c#, xunit.net, fscheck, property-based-testing

I'm trying to use FsCheck to write a basic property based test for a class that generates random `DateTimeOffset` values in a given interval.

```
[Property]
public void ValueBetweenMinAndMax(DateTimeOffset min, DateTimeOffset max)
{
    var sut = new DateTimeOffsetGenerator();
    DateTimeOffset actual = sut.Next(min, max);
    Assert.True(min <= actual);
    Assert.True(max >= actual);
}
```

That test fails pretty quickly when `min`> `max` because I validate the input parameters of `Next()` and throw an `ArgumentException`in that case.

```
public DateTimeOffset Next(DateTimeOffset min, DateTimeOffset max)
{
    if (min > max)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(min));
    }

    // ...
}
```

I don't want to change the implementation to swap the input parameters. And I don't want to do that in the test method either.

Is there a way to teach FsCheck to generate the `min` and `max` values with the constraint that `min` must never be greater that `max`?

Samples in C# would be greatly appreciated because my knowledge about F# is not up to par.

Comment: if you ask for a min input and a variance input, then compute max from min+variance, you can pass that onward to express this

Comment: @RubenBartelink Unfortunately that would still require an Arbitrary (to generate only positive TimeSpans) plus logic to protect from overflow (DateTimeOffset.MaxValue + 10s) inside the test method. I still like the idea. It might come in handy elsewhere.

Comment: my point is to ask for an int as an input argument to the FsCheck.xUnit [Propery], then use that `%` <some limit> - i.e. preprocess and pass it on

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved the problem like this

```
[Property(Arbitrary = new[] { typeof(MyArbitraries) })]
public void ValueBetweenMinAndMax((DateTimeOffset minValue, DateTimeOffset maxValue) bounds)
{
    // ...
}

public static class MyArbitraries
{
    public static Arbitrary<(DateTimeOffset minValue, DateTimeOffset maxValue)> DateTimeOffsetBounds()
    {
        return (from minValue in Arb.Generate<DateTimeOffset>()
                from maxValue in Arb.Generate<DateTimeOffset>()
                where minValue <= maxValue
                select (minValue, maxValue))
            .ToArbitrary();
    }
}
```

I wanted the test parameters to match the signature of the sut to keep the test as easy to understand as possible. Pre-processing parameters would have distracted from what I actually wanted to test.

Nonetheless the alternative pointed out by @Ruben is still a good one.